# Split comma separated string and insert into new table with corresponding PK

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with values like this.

```
PK   Values
1    abc,def,ghy,tyu
2    qwe,tyu,iop,fgt
```

I want to split the CSV and make a new table like this

```
Id    Value
1     abc
1     def
1     ghy
1     tyu
2     qwe
2     tyu
2     iop
2     fgt
```

I already have split function but i need a query to align the values with corresponding PK

Comment: I found it fairly easy to take one of the answers in the duplicate link, change the table and columns names, and get your expected output.  Next time you should share the query you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
Select t.Id,f.SplitData AS Value from #MyTable t
CROSS APPLY dbo.fnSplitString([Values],',') f
```